# Install Foxitreader 2 for all users

Tags: software-installation, foxitreader

I have downloaded `FoxitReader2.2.1025_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar.gz`. When I extract it and execute it it tries to install in my user's home directory. I believe that way it is not accessible by other users.

How can I install it to be accessible by other users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install to the system rather than your `$HOME` (and thus make Foxit accessible to all users) simply run the install script with elevated privileges:

```
sudo ./FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.1.0805\(r225432\).x64.run
```

Specify a *system* path in the 'Installation Folder' box that comes up:

[image]

And all should be well. The installer does not fully comprehend the use of `sudo` but rest assured it will be a system-wide installation and available to all users...

**References:**

- [How to Install Foxit PDF Reader 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 or Any Linux Distro](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-foxit-pdf-reader-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: By the way it needs *qt5-default*.